# Get the item set as display

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a container x, with a Link item y set as display.
How can I access programmatically y if I know x?

I tried: `getattr(x, 'default_page', None)`, but it returns None all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `getattr` you may override plone default behavior regarding how to determinate the default page of an object (item or container).

Content objects in Plone inherit `BrowserDefaultMixin`, [which provides the functionality of getting the default page of a object](https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/2.10.4/plone/dexterity/content.py#L730)

The [mixin](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI/blob/6.0.3/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py#L91), respectively [a utility](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/5.2.5/Products/CMFPlone/PloneTool.py#L540) used by the mixin provides the desired method called `getDefaultPage`

```
>>> x = b.getObject()
>>> x.getDefaultPage()
...
```

This will return the right `content object` or `view` depending on the configuration on the object, on the FTI and on the View itself and more.

Have a look at [`get_default_page`](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/5.2.5/Products/CMFPlone/defaultpage.py#L19) for more details.

And even better...
This canonical way of getting the default page, would also have helped finding the issue in your case pretty fast, since the method does certain checks to make sure the passed object provides the right "features". A string would not pass those checks.

Answer (score 0):

`default_page = getattr(x, 'default_page', None)` is the answer. But make sure you have an object for x.

My mistake was I tried `b.getObject().absolute_url()` in my query instead of `b.getObject()`.